# How to save rotations that I manually made by my mouse in the Cloud?

Tags: plotting

If, for example, I plot a ball and rotate it manually by my mouse: How can I save the result of the rotation?

Answer (score 2):

Your view depends on many options like `ViewAngle`, `ViewCenter`, `ViewPoint` and ...

If you want to only save the rotation, insert these code:

```
AbsoluteOptions[ PLOT , ViewPoint]
```

#### Example

```
Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

Produces:

[image]

Rotate the plot and insert the code:

[image]

```
(*Out: {ViewPoint -> {-1.46875, -2.45303, 1.8098}} *)
```

Use the result in your plot option to get the same `ViewPoint`:

```
Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, ViewPoint -> {-1.46875, -2.45303, 1.8098}]
```

Result:

[image]

The same method can be applied to other view-related options.